# sqlite-android-How to encrypt data and put them in sqlite

Tags: java, php, android, sqlite, encode

I need an offline database for my app . You know , if someone root his phone , he can easily access the database and use the data, I've lots of data and I need to protect it .

I thought the best way is to encode data before I put them in the database and decode them in java and use the correct data.

I'm using php/mysql to retrieve the data .How can I encode these data and put them in sqlite and decode it in java ?

thanks you

Answer (score 1):

Use an encryption library.  There's plenty out there, don't write your own.  But here's why this won't work well-  you'll have the decryption key and the data on the same device (the key would be in your app).  Its trivial for the attacker to grab it from the apk.  If you want to have real security, you'll need to get the decryption key from a web service each time you run so the key isn't ever stored on the device.

Comment: sir is there a way to store log in data like password and username safety in database only?i mean from what i understand on your answer it is not safe to encrypt password and save it on device..

Comment: @HakHak He mentioned _get the decryption key from a web service_ while you have the data like password on the device

Comment: @Griddoor sorry im question was a bit off..what im trying to ask is what if my device does not require internet connection and i still want to keep it safe is there a way?

Comment: @HakHak I can't think of any. I guess asking the user to manually input the key is not an option.

Comment: @Griddoor that would mean the user need to memorize like 32 characters for the key?that would be troublesome...thank you for the answer mate..

Comment: as an alternate, you may use device's bluetooth/wifi-mac/gsm-number address or some sort of android GUID (if available) to use as encryption key. I know its not elegant but at least your database's encryption will be specific to that device :)

Comment: thanks for the reply , What is the best library and exactly what they do ? for example ,If I have a db full of data, How does this library encode it ? My database is gonna be downloaded from internet (just one time). Should I encode it before or I get the database and then encode it ?